# Update title for a custom navigation bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, titlebar

I have a custom navigation bar that I have created from my Storyboard and dragged an `IBOutlet` to it, but I cant´t figure out how to change to title for it dynamically. My `navigationBar` does not have any title attribute on it.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure but self.title="" in viewwillAppear will work I guess

Or         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""

Comment: what do you mean by custom? Also by changing dynamically, you want to update the title from your code many times?

Comment: please provide your custom class code

Comment: A 'custom navigation bar' normally means you have subclassed UINavigationBar. Do you mean you have added a UINavigationBar to your view?

Comment: @Leon, yes. @RashwanL´s answer solved my issue. Sorry if I was unclear in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your custom `navigationBar` you have an attribute called `topItem`:

> The navigation item at the top of the navigation bar’s stack.

Use it to change your title for your custom `navigationBar` like this:

```
navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Some title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create outlet of title of custom navigation bar and set myTitle.title = "new title"

[image]

Comment: I need it dynamically

Comment: You added navigation bar dynamically?